# Large csv file import into phpmyadmin - again - other answers not working

Tags: import, phpmyadmin

Ok I have tried several things but nothing seems to work for me. I have set the max file size to 750M, and added execution time in php.ini. I have set auto commit to 0. And I have used this:

> LOAD DATA INFILE 'YOUR_FILE_COMPLETE_PATH' INTO TABLE tbl_name
>   FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"'   LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'

It did not work. I get:

> 0 rows inserted. (Query took 0.0002 seconds.)

When I use the import form in phpmyadmin it times out (even though it is set to 5000 in php.ini) and only adds about 3,000 rows at a time (not good for a file with 273,000 rows.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You will have a problem with importing using phpMyAdmin, due to low memory and bandwidth, if you ever try to increase PHP config info, maybe you get data imported but you will face outage. I can suggest 3 option:

1) Use [BigDump](https://www.ozerov.de/bigdump/usage/) which is a library for this type of jobs.

2) Convert your data to .sql and import using Mysql dump:

```
mysql -u username -p database_name < file.sql
```

3) Also you can use [mysqlimport](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqlimport.html) to import CSV:

```
mysqlimport --ignore-lines=1 \
            --fields-terminated-by=, \
            --local -u root \
            -p Database \
             TableName.csv
```